# Button click using the webViewClient

Tags: android, webviewclient

I am using WebView in my application.I load an url using the WebView.On loading the page , it contains many links and buttons . i want to handle the click of a particular button of the page. How to implement this.?

Answer (score 0):

In webview if you are using loadUrl() method and passing url there then webview will directly open that url. so you will get all the click events which are present in that url if you click there then you will be redirected to new intent. SO no need of putting your own click event in webview data.

Is there any special reason behind that. Can you please elaborate what do you wan to perform?

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: hi thanks of yur reply. well... ya i am loading a URL using  loadUrl().in the loaded page i have a button on clicking which it does nothing and the page remains the same. so i want to get capture the on click of that particular button in the page and proceed with the further functionality.